# How to setup a standard message to my Discord Bot in case someone send a PM to him?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is my first post and I don't know if I am doing it correctly but, I want just this. I am programming a Discord Bot and I want that when I send a message to him on PM it says some standard message in order to specify that is a bot and maybe put some information. I just tested the commands I've setup and he is answering the commands and shits. I want also to ignore everything and just answer when you write to him. The clear example is the Ticket Tool, something like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlzSH.png

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `message` event handler you can add this line

```js
// if message is not in a server
if (!message.guild) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: so, how it could be if i want to answer the simple string: "Hey, I am a bot. Better don't PM me"